# Github Simple Commit Issue

Tags: github

I made modifications to my github repo on the actual website rather than the terminal. Now, I can't commit anything locally from my computer to my terminal because it says the files stored locally are not in sync with the github repo. How can I fix this so I can push my changes in terminal? Can I undo my previous commits that I did on the website?

Comment: ... Did you try pulling from the repo to your computer before pushing?

Answer (score 1):

1. (Optional) If you've some modifications locally, stash them first:

```
$  git stash
```

2. Because you've made some modifications at remote repo, you need to pull them down before pushing new commits (fix conflicts one by one if you got in this step):

```
$ git pull origin your_branch
```

3. Now your local branch & remote branch are in same stage, get back previously stashed modifications back (if you did step #1 before):

```
$ git stash pop  
$ git add .  
$ git commit -m "commit msg here"
```

4. It's OK to push local modifications to remote then:

```
$ git push origin your_branch
```

---

Btw, if you did modification at remote repo BY MISTAKE, and just want to use local repo as latest, you can push local repo to overwrite remote one (make sure remote repo's branch is not protected by server):

```
// !!! Use it wisely & carefully, cause it will overwrite the whole branch at remote side.
//
$ git push -f origin your_branch
```